# Regarding SPI modes

Tags: spi

I have doubt on SPI modes.
from online source i got this image
[image]

from this image, for modes 0 & 3 Sampling edge is Rising edge and Transmit edge is Falling edge.

Is this the same case for SPI master & Slave.
I mean if i have SPI flash & SPI master supporting both modes. Whether this sampling at Rising edge & transmitting at falling edge holds for Both SPI master & SPI flash also. or only for SPI flash and reverse for SPI master(sampling @ falling edge , Transmit @ Rising edge)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPI slaves do not control the CPOL and CPHA values, the master does. So the master has to use a mode that the slave(s) will accept. Usually, the slaves will be compatible enough that they will all work with one set of settings. But if not, the master can change mode to talk to a specific device.

Answer (score 1):

Both the master and the slave have to be in the same SPI mode so for both sampling would be rising and transmit would be falling.