# How to change SPI mode externally?

Tags: microcontroller, spi

My MCU only supports mode 0 and mode 3 in hardware. Yet my slave only supports mode 2.

It works when bitbanging, but I'd like to benefit from the HW SPI for increased speed and lower overhead.

As those SPI modes are just phase/level conventions, I'm thinking about simply adding an inverter on the clock line such as a 2N3904 or even a 4069.

Whould that be a good idea or is there a better way?

Note: *The modes are the ones described in [Regarding SPI modes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/regarding-spi-modes) but my question tries to be more generic. The particular context only serving as am example.*

Comment: What is 0 mode and mode 3 in hardware? Which MCU are you using? Can you be specific?

Comment: Mode 0-3 ... these are not standardized in SPI ... It depends on vendor what timing is actually there for each mode... So you may want to provide some timing diagrams / reference for the master and slave SPI modes along with this question ...

Comment: I can be more specific, But I tried to ask it in a very generic manner. As in the end I'd like to know how to change mode without changing the software.

Comment: What MCU is it, and what SPI slave it is? You have a very specific problem, as in general, changing the mode externally in hardware is very rare. Also the mode numbers do not mean anything, they are arbitrary, and you need to look at chip datasheet timing charts if they are compatible, not mode numbers.

Comment: MCU is CH552 and slave is ST7789 that is configured with SPI_MODE2 from Arduino on the breakout board.

Comment: replying to myself, looking at the various datasheets, 2904 is the slowest (400ns)  then 4069 (200ns). 74HC14 would fit best with its 20ns. Will test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device SPI modes look compatible. You don't need to do anything.

The ST7789 anyway requires to load in data at rising clock edge, i.e. in the middle of a bit, so at least you can't invert the clock and you must use one of the two modes already provided by CH552.

But in the event of requiring the other two SPI modes for some other chip, just invert the clock and you have a falling clock edge in the middle of a bit. It can be inverted with a 74HC04.